# is it possible to create a notepad using xml file in android?

Tags: android, xml-serialization, xml

i have to make a notepad where i write,edit,clear the text.

this notepad need to save on sd card as an xml file.

i also need to read the file when it will in sd card.

i am new in android and i can not understand how to manage it.

```
<Title>
<edittext>
<path>(xml file saved in sd card)...</path></edittext></title>
```

then this xml need to call by activty.

is there any possible way or any easiest way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an Android notepad tutorial: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/index.html

It would be a good place to start.

If you are trying to load the notepad text, then you'll need to do that in code. Something like

```
<EditText
   android:id="@+id/editor"
   .../>
```

Then in code,

```
String savedText = loadTextFromFile();
EditText editor = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editor);
editor.setText(savedText);
```

Then you just need to write the `loadTextFromFile()` method to actually get the notepad text. This is the same as you would do it in Java.

Comment: here the link is done by using the activity.but i have to create the notepad using xml.ok.i am tryin using your instruction.